# Head (and shoulder) detection using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

(Appology in advance if I am asking a too nwbie question. I am a beginner with OpenCV. I have done some tutorials yet I have not a good grasp of it's concepts.)

Question: How to do head detection (not face detection) using OpenCV - For example in a photo of inside a bus or a room?

Note: I do not want to do face detection; just head detection to figure out number of people in the photo. Unfortunately - for me - those tutorials and documents that I'v found are about face detection and not head detection.

Thank you

Comment: Don't these face detection algorithms start by first detecting heads to later analyse the inner content of these shapes that might be heads to check whether it is a face or not?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have looked into facedetect.cpp in facedetect sample in samples directory. I detectAndDraw function - I am not fluent in OpenCV nor in C or C++ but - It seems to use some points on the face itself not the head.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian, hello. Did you find solution for head detection? I'm looking for the same and only way I currently see is to train haar.

Comment: It was nearly five years ago and the project dismissed shortly after. I've used OpenCV later but not for this purpose. So I do not remember much. But keep in mind the `Head & Shoulder` phrase used wrongly here. That phrase refers to some sort of diagram - good to know.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at all the Haar boosted classifiers that are available with OpenCV and the dedicated class [`CascadeClassifier`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier) to use it. Here are a list of what the classifiers have locally:

- haarcascade_eye.xml
- haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
- haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
- haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
- **haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml**
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml
- haarcascade_profileface.xml
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml
- haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml
- **haarcascade_upperbody.xml**
- haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml
- haarcascade_fullbody.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml

The two I bolded may be of special interest to you. Try those as a start for your project. As [Alessandro Vermeulen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682376/alessandro-vermeulen) commented, head detection classifiers may also be interesting, as what they find is usely connected to shoulders :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! But I can't find head detection classifiers :(

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian : head detection classifiers are those containing `frontalface` in their names. There are 4 of them. You can't find a head without a face (say seen from the back), as it is a way more complex problem, due to the hair.

Comment: Thanks; Finding a head - even without a face - is exactly what I want. So I think I should learn how to train OpenCV using HAAR classifiers to detect heads (If it is possible).

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian : the closest I know is [this](http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2acc9f6def44c8ac55cd7ca3b0e2d2cdc/wyswilson)

Comment: @StéphanePéchard link is broken 404

Comment: Did you find a classifier for that purpose @KavehShahbazian?

Comment: Sorry @Mostafa! I don't really remember much about that project! But we did it. I remember a bit about working on pedestrian recognition, problem had changed I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can as well create your own cascade classifier to detect heads. The upper body is not the head at all, but just heads is not that accurate. You need to crop several number of positive samples and negative ones. Prepare list of these example in text.txt, opencv_createsamples.exe(prepare input vector for training) and use opencv_traincascade.exe command line utility to create opencv classifier for cascade detect multiscale.
It is easy but the creating the dataset is time consuming. My head LBP cascade is available here for free download [link to my blog for head, car and people cascade](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2020/03/download-CascadeClassifier-haar-LBP-head-car-people-detection.html) . It is compatible with detectMultiscale, but not that accurate.